# What account am I logged in with?

Tags: support, profile-page, login

How do I know which account / email address I'm logged in with on Stack Overflow?

Usually when you log into a websites, it greets you with "Hello Jane" / "Hello George" - or displays the person's email address in the top corner.

I know I'm logged in now, but I have no references on Stack Overflow to say this. (Just slight changes in the top menu - but these don't tell me "I'm logged in").

Am I logged in with `sarah@personal.com` or `sarah@business.com`?

Comment: Click on your user name right above this comment to the right. Look for the "email" field

Comment: Look in the footer of the site -- there are site links on every page.

Comment: Hover over your avatar.  It will show you your username.  click on your avatar.  You can see all of your details, including e-mail.

Comment: "Ps, theres no where on http://stackoverflow.com to easily find subdomains - EG meta.stackoverflow.com" Yes, maybe make it easier to find chat.stackoverflow?